# Download Teach Tracks to iTunes

Tags: itunes, music

I downloaded Teach Tracks to learn songs and I like to add them to playlists.  How do I add these to my Apple Music cloud library so that I can then add them to playlists in iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 'teach tracks' are DRM free and not buy from iTunes you could add them to iTunes as long as their fileformat is compatible with iTunes. You don't need an Apple Cloud Library to create playlists, just create a playlist with these songs inside itunes. You can then transfer the songs and the playlist to an iPhone/iPod just by connecting it to your computer.
If you still want your songs in iCloud you must subscribe to iTunes Match from apple. Your songs will be match with iTunes catalog to be available in the cloud from your account, if a song doesn't match the itunes catalog it will be upload to the cloud in order to be available.

If your songs are bought from iTunes they are already available in the cloud.